# class with float variable

Tags: c++

I have a simple class here with a variable. Why does it not return the value of the variable `10.5`?

## output

```
Test! -1.09356e+09
```

## code

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

class Txtbin{
    protected:
        float area;

    public:
        Txtbin();
        float get_area();
};

Txtbin::Txtbin(){
    float area = 10.5;
}

float Txtbin::get_area(){
    return area;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Txtbin a;
    cout << "Test! " << a.get_area() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Mine tells](http://ideone.com/izrx32) `Test! 0`.

Comment: Undefined behavior because you print the indeterminate value of an uninitialized member variable.

Comment: And that's why you compile with warnings, and pay attention to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is creating a local variable, not initializing your member:

```
Txtbin::Txtbin(){
    float area = 10.5; // creates a variable called area that isn't used.
}
```

You should initialize your member like this

```
Txtbin::Txtbin()
: area(10.5)
{
}
```

Or perhaps directly in the class if you are using C++11 or newer:

```
class Txtbin{
    protected:
        float area = 10.5;

    public:
        Txtbin();
        float get_area();
};
```

Comment: When I init the variable directly I get this `txtbin.cpp:11:16: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   float area = 10.5;
`

Comment: @clarkk: That's right.  I'm guessing you are using gcc.  It doesn't use C++11 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your new `area` declaration here shadows the member.

```
Txtbin::Txtbin(){
    float area = 10.5;
}
```

If you enable more/all warnings, the compiler will probably tell you as much.

e.g.

```
$ clang++ -Weverything tmp/foo.cpp
tmp/foo.cpp:16:11: warning: declaration shadows a field of 'Txtbin' [-Wshadow]
    float area = 10.5;
          ^
tmp/foo.cpp:8:15: note: previous declaration is here
        float area;
              ^
tmp/foo.cpp:16:11: warning: unused variable 'area' [-Wunused-variable]
    float area = 10.5;
          ^
tmp/foo.cpp:23:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
             ^
tmp/foo.cpp:23:26: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
                         ^
4 warnings generated.
```

Instead do this, use a member initializer in the constructor.

```
class Txtbin{
    protected:
        float area;

    public:
        Txtbin();
        float get_area();
};

Txtbin::Txtbin()
   : area(10.5) {
}
```